# Cast between structs from different scopes

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I am interested in casting between pointers to structs that are potentially compatible. They'll use the same tag, the same members in the same order. Although the target codebase is compiled as either C or C++, for the sake of simplifying this question I would like to restrict this to C++ only.

This is a situation where I am confident that the compiler will behave reasonably, but I cannot find supporting evidence that it is required to do so.

The motivating code example is:

```
#include <cstdio>

void foo(void * arg)
{
    struct example
    {
        int a;
        const char * b;
    };

    example * myarg = static_cast<example *>(arg);
    printf("meaning of %s is %d\n",myarg->b,myarg->a);
}

void bar(void)
{
    struct example
    {
        int a;
        const char * b;
    };

    example on_stack {42, "life"};
    foo(&on_stack);
}

int main(int,char**)
{
    bar();
}
```

I have had less luck with the C++11 standard. Section 9 on classes suggests the examples will be "layout-compatible", which sounds encouraging, but I can't find a description of the consequences of structures being "layout-compatible". In particular, can I cast a pointer of one to a pointer of the other without consequences?

A colleague believes "layout-compatible" means memcpy will work as expected. Given that the struct in question is also always trivially copyable, it is possible that the following nominally inefficient code would avoid UB:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void foo(void * arg)
{
    struct example
    {
        int a;
        const char * b;
    };

    example local;
    std::memcpy(&local, arg, sizeof(example));
    printf("meaning of %s is %d\n", local.b, local.a);
}

// bar and main as before
```

The actual motivation for this is to get the struct definition out of global scope when it's only used for communication between a small number of functions. I appreciate that it is debatable whether this is a good idea.

Comment: Please pick one language. This is C++ code and then you quote C11.

Comment: The target codebase compiles cleanly as C89, C99, C11, C++98, C++03 and C++11. It needs to continue doing so.

Comment: No it doesn't. `#include <cstdio>`, `static_cast`...

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, the example above that writes trivia to stdout is not the application I'm actually interested in. I'll append a C89 version. If you're really keen, I'll mash the two together with #ifdef as well, but it's not likely to clarify matters.

Comment: I started to write an answer but soon deleted it as I realized that C and C++ are very different when it comes to rules about type punning and pointer aliasing, which is essential to mention in any decent answer.  I'm fed up with questions about the "C/C++ language". Bye.

Comment: I'd be greatful for an answer covering either. I'm not asking about the "C/C++ language", I'm asking about a piece of code that happens to get included in C projects and in C++ projects. It's tedious to work in the common subset, but not as tedious as maintaining two nearly identical projects.

Comment: In C++, I'm pretty sure this is illegal type punning. These two are distinct types (by way of having no linkage). They are layout-compatible, but the only thing this gives you is that, if somehow they are together in a union, you can access either. See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing (which explicitly states that being layout-compatible does not by itself exempt types from strict aliasing rules; while not normative, it's a good summary of the standard).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you could argue that the struct itself is never punned; the only lvalues read are `int` and `const char *`  and they do in fact access objects of the right type

Comment: IMO this is moot as it is trivial to avoid the problem by actualy using common struct definition

Comment: Why not include a common struct within both structs; one way of doing inheritance in C?  I have also done this in C (again, for OOP in C) using defines that include "base" members, and it has never failed me. Although I don't have a reference to the specification that says it will work, as long as one of those doesn't end up within a #pack, it should work.  The bonus with the first method (common struct) is that you avoid dangerous casting!!!  That's the real problem you might have here - if you DO add a member to one of those, the cast will IGNORE it, resulting in hours of debugging.

Comment: @c.fogelklou I'm not sure how containing a common struct helps here - it would need to be visible to both functions, and at that point I may as well make the example struct visible. Updating one and forgetting the other is solvable with macros...

Comment: A more standard, safer way to do this is to define the struct at the top of the file where all of the functions exist.  Doing it your way, you are REALLY exposed to copy/paste errors down the line, being forced to update the struct in many places without the compiler EVER complaining that you forgot one.  If the functions are dispersed in several files, then just create a header that contains ONLY that struct and is included ONLY from those files.  I would personally never do things as in your example as it produces an enormous amount of technical debt.

Comment: @JonChesterfield use macros then.  Using the common struct OR macros prevents you from accruing technical debt when you need to modify code in more than one place.  As I said, I have used both common structs AND macros, but it is bad coding practice to copy and paste definitions since it opens up for errors.

Comment: @JonChesterfield To clarify why a common struct is better (avoiding casting).  With macros you must cast:  BaseObj *pA = static_cast<BaseObj *>(&a), which will cast anything to anything, whereas with a common struct, you avoid the dangerous cast: BaseObj *pA = &a.common; - won't compile if a.common isn't a BaseObj, and also allows you to move "common" to somewhere else in the struct.

Comment: @M.M `myarg->a` is equivalent to `(*myarg).a` which would seem to mean that `*myarg` lvalue is in fact being accessed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yeah it is unclear. I wouldn't say that `(*myarg).a` accessess all of `*myarg`, just `a`. But I see how you would say that. In C2x this exact issue is being addressed, IDK if there is any equivalent effort for C++

Comment: @M.M Consider: `struct S{int a, b;}; int x=42; S* p = (S*)( (char*)&x - offsetof(S, b) ); p->b = 84; /* assigns to x */` Would you say this is legal now (because an lvalue of type `S` is not accessed, just `S::b` which does happen to have valid storage underneath), or should be made legal? It looks quite sketchy to me, at best.

Comment: I think it's unclear but probably legal (assuming no alignment violation), and sketchy

Comment: If they are `potentially` compatible why not to create `base class` (or `interface`) and use `dynamic_cast`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now clear (thanks to [Nicol Bolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37368823)) that direct aliasing between two structs that are simply layout compatible would invoke UB because of the strict aliasing rule.

Of course you can memcopy the content, but:

- it may be expensive depending of struct size
- you only get a copy (changes will not be reflected) unless you memcopy back when done

But... you can create in C++ a struct of references that point to the original values. It will aliases directly members to their original type which is now perfectly defined by the standard.

Code for foo could become:

```
void foo(void * arg)
{
    struct example // only used to declare the layout
    {
        int a;
        const char * b;
    };
    struct r_example {
    int &a;
    const char *&b;
    r_example(void *ext): a(*(static_cast<int*>(ext))),
        b(*(reinterpret_cast<const char **>(
            static_cast<char*>(ext) + offsetof(example, b)))) {}
    };


    r_example myarg(arg);
    printf("in foo meaning of %s is %d\n",myarg.b,myarg.a);
    myarg.a /= 2;
}
```

And the change introduced in last line is visible without UB in caller:

```
void bar(void)
{
    struct example
    {
        int a;
        const char * b;
    };

    example on_stack {42, "life"};
    foo(&on_stack);
    printf("after foo meaning of %s is %d\n",on_stack.b,on_stack.a);
}
```

Will display:

```
in foo meaning of life is 42
after foo meaning of life is 21
```

The C counterpart, will use pointers instead of refs:

```
    struct p_example {
        int *a;
        const char **b;
    } my_arg;
    my_arg.a = (int *) ext;
    my_arg.b = (const char **)(((char*)ext) + offsetof(example, b));

    printf("in foo meaning of %s is %d\n",*(myarg.b),*(myarg.a));
    *(myarg.a) /= 2;
```

Comment: Glorious! Great use of offsetof to thwart namespace pollution. This will work nicely, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Does [basic.lval] 10.6 allow aliasing between layout compatible types? No. The section in question states:

> an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union)

Recall that "the aforementioned types" are the actual type `T`, the dynamic type of `T`, a type that is similar to the dynamic type, some const/volatile qualified version of the dynamic type, or a signed/unsigned version of the dynamic type.

Now, consider this code:

```
struct T {int i;};
struct U {int i;};

T t;
U *pu = (U*)&t;
pu->i = 5;
```

Now, let's look at 10.6 in that light. The question 10.6 asks is if the glvalue's type `U` contains a member that fits the qualifications of 10.1-10.5. Does it? Remember that the dynamic type of the object `t` is `T`.

- Does `U` contain a member of type `T`? No.
- Does `U` contain a member which is a const/volatile qualified version of `T`? No.
- Does `U` contain a member that is of a type which is similar to `T`? No.
- Does `U` contain a member that is a signed/unsigned version of `T`? No.
- Does `U`contain a member that is a const/volatile qualified version of a signed/unsigned version of `T`? No.

Since all of those fail, the compiler is allowed to assume that modifying the object pointed to by `pu` will *not* modify the object `t`.

---

FYI:

> Anyway, memcopy and pointer aliasing is exactly the same, except for global struct alignment.

No, they aren't. The rules for trivial copy-ability and layout compatibility are not at all the same as the rules for aliasing.

Trivial copyability is about the sanity of copying the value representation of an object and whether such a copy represents a legitimate object. The rules of layout compatibility are about whether the value representation of `A` is compatible with `B`, such that a value of `A` could be copied into an object of type `B`.

Aliasing is about saying whether it is possible to access an object through a pointer/reference to `A` and a pointer/reference to `B` at the same time. The strict aliasing rule states that if the compiler sees a `A& a` and a `B& b`, the compiler is allowed to assume that modifications made through `a` *will not affect* the object referenced through `b`, and vice-versa. [basic.lval] 10 outlines the cases when the compiler is not allowed to assume this.

Comment: Regarding your explanation for the purpose of [3.10p6]: If we were to map the standard text to your example, the text allows you to access the object denoted by `u.t` through `u`, or `u.t.i` through `u`; your example does the opposite. Moreover, your example doesn't test if `u` taken as a whole has been modified, but rather if `u.t.i` has been; `u.t.i` is a glvalue of type `int`, used to access an object of type `int`, which has also been accessed through another glvalue of type `int`, `j.i`; that's all, and it's already covered by 10p1. I don't think 10p6 comes into play in this example.

Comment: The thing is, I don't think there's a way to make 10p6 come into play in C++. You don't access the object denoted by `u.t` through `u` itself, taken as a whole; you always use a glvalue like `u.t` that actually has the type of the subobject. I think this is supported by [CWG2051](http://wg21.link/cwg2051), which does give some info about this bullet, indicating that it is actually redundant in C++, and it's only useful in C for copying structs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nicol Bolas's answer that you **can't** access type through another type even if they are *layout-compatible*. I will just to add what *layout-compatible* means

N3337 9.2/17

> Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types **are layout-compatible** if they have the **same number of non-static
>   data members** and corresponding **non-static data members** ( **in declaration order** ) **have layout-compatible
>   types** (3.9).

---

Now to explain all terms here:

(Note that *layout compatible **types*** and *layout-compatible **standard-layout structs*** are 2 different things)

**1. Layout compatible type**

*layout-compatible type* means *same type*:

N3337 3.9/11:

> **If** two types **T1 and T2 are the same type**, then **T1 and T2 are *layout-compatible types***.

**2. Standard-Layout struct:**

N3337 9/8

> A standard-layout struct is a *standard-layout class* defined with the *class-key* struct or the *class-key* class.

(Or in other words (because C++ refers to structs,unions and classes as just *class*) it is *standard-layout class* that is not union)

*Standard-layout class* is:

N3337 9/7

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with
>     non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.
>     108
>
> 108) This ensures that two subobjects that have the same class type and that belong to the same most derived object are not
>   allocated at the same address (5.10)